Add a new column name to each line with little repeated effort
It would be useful to type in a parameter and return a column index. Any solutions?
Here is version of what works, but can only type in one colName value at a time to change the index value and doesn't have much value for repeat application.
colName = "Inv#"
colIndex = Worksheets("Invoice Database").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(colName).Range(1, 1).Column
MsgBox (colIndex) 'returns column index of 1

The following is a hypothetical solution without having to declare the colName string in each instance.
colIndex(colName) = Worksheets("Invoice Database").ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(colName).Range(1, 1).Column
msgBox (colIndex("Inv#")) 'returns column index of 1
msgBox (colIndex("Full Name)) 'returns column index of 2
msgBox (colIndex("Service Date)) 'returns column index of 3


You can create a function like this
Public Function colIndex(colName As String) As Long

Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = Worksheets("Invoice Database").ListObjects("Table2")

colIndex = lo.ListColumns(colName).Index

End Function

And then use it like this:
Sub test()
MsgBox colIndex("Inv#")
MsgBox colIndex("Full name")
End Sub


Thank you, it works perfectly for what I am needing to do.
